# Password Generator

Tags: bash

re-learning bash from being at uni, and making a password generator. I want to be able to output the results to a text file can anyone help? my code so far is:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Password Generator

#Account Name
echo "What account is this password for"
read account

#username
echo "Please give your username"
read username

#ask for password length

echo "please provide a password length"
read length

echo "Your password is"
openssl rand -base64 $length
```

I would like to be able to output the results from account, username, and what the password is to the text file
Thanks in advance for any help, and i hope this query makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, but ultimately only 2 approaches: pipe to a file, or pipe to a program that writes to a file.

I've created some modified versions of your scripts below, demonstrating some methods.

#### Output To A New File (Gedit):

```
#!/bin/bash
#Password Generator A 1.1
#A random password generator written for Bash.
#Dependencies: Gedit, OpenSSL
##Request Inputs
###Account Name
echo -n "Account Name:"
read account
###Username
echo -n "Username:"
read username
###Password Length
echo -n "Password length:"
read length
##Generate Password 
password=$(openssl rand -base64 $length)
##Generate Result
###Merge variables
output=$(echo -e "Account Name:${account}\nUsername:${username}\nPassword:${password}")
##Output result
###Output to terminal
echo "$output"
###Output to new file in Gedit
echo "$output" | gedit -
exit 0
```

#### Output To A New File (Nano):

```
#!/bin/bash
#Password Generator B 1.1
#A random password generator written for Bash.
#Dependencies: Nano, OpenSSL
##Request Inputs
###Account Name
echo -n "Account Name:"
read account
###Username
echo -n "Username:"
read username
###Password Length
echo -n "Password length:"
read length
##Generate Password 
password=$(openssl rand -base64 $length)
##Generate Result
###Merge variables
output=$(echo -e "Account Name:${account}\nUsername:${username}\nPassword:${password}")
##Output result
###Output to terminal
echo "$output"
###Output to new file in Nano
echo "$output" | nano -
exit 0
```

#### Output To A Text File Located At "~/output":

```
#!/bin/bash
#Password Generator C 1.1
#A random password generator written for Bash.
#Dependencies: OpenSSL
##Request Inputs
###Account Name
echo -n "Account Name:"
read account
###Username
echo -n "Username:"
read username
###Password Length
echo -n "Password length:"
read length
##Generate Password 
password=$(openssl rand -base64 $length)
##Generate Result
###Merge variables
output=$(echo -e "Account Name:${account}\nUsername:${username}\nPassword:${password}")
##Output result
###Output to terminal
echo "$output"
###Output to file
echo "$output" > "$HOME/output"
exit 0
```

### Output To A Text File Located At "~/output" (Using Tee):

```
#!/bin/bash
#Password Generator D 1.1
#A random password generator written for Bash.
#Dependencies: Tee, OpenSSL
##Request Inputs
###Account Name
echo -n "Account Name:"
read account
###Username
echo -n "Username:"
read username
###Password Length
echo -n "Password length:"
read length
##Generate Password 
password=$(openssl rand -base64 $length)
##Generate Result
###Merge variables
output=$(echo -e "Account Name:${account}\nUsername:${username}\nPassword:${password}")
##Output result
###Output to terminal & file
echo "$output" | tee "$HOME/output"
exit 0
```

### Output To A Text File (User chooses):

```
#!/bin/bash
#Password Generator E 1.1
#A random password generator written for Bash.
#Dependencies: OpenSSL
##Request Inputs
###Account Name
echo -n "Account Name:"
read account
###Username
echo -n "Username:"
read username
###Password Length
echo -n "Password length:"
read length
###Save Location
echo -n "Save to:"
read savelocation
##Generate Password 
password=$(openssl rand -base64 $length)
##Generate Result
###Merge variables
output=$(echo -e "Account Name:${account}\nUsername:${username}\nPassword:${password}")
##Output result
###Output to terminal
echo "$output"
###Output to file
echo "$output" > "$savelocation"
exit 0
```

Comment: Cheers for that!!! Not a great coder but trying to improve what i know and thats a great help!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect any output with echo like: cmd > filename
or in your case:

```
openssl rand -base64 $length > passwords.txt
```

Comment: thank you for helping, knew it would be a simple answer but couldnt work it out!!!

Comment: Please vote up the answer if it helped. Thank you.